# How to cd to a folder with two dots in the path

Tags: linux

I am removing some files on my CentOS server which a virus scan has deemed to be infected.

Two of the files have ".." in the path. I understand that normally `..` is how we navigate up to the parent directory. In this case the two dots seem to be part of the actual path.

For example, if the path of the file is:

```
/var/lib/mysql/mysql/..\bin\cna12.dll
```

Then I can cd to:

```
/var/lib/mysql/mysql/
```

If I then type cd and press tab twice, I am offered the option to autocomplete to several options. One of the options is:

```
..\bin\cna12.dll
```

See it in this pasted text (notice it in the first column):

```
..\bin\cna12.dll                    help_topic.frm                      slow_log.CSV
columns_priv.frm                    help_topic.MYD                      slow_log.frm
columns_priv.MYD                    help_topic.MYI                      tables_priv.frm
```

Normally I can type a few characters of the autocomplete suggestions and press tab again to bring the autocomplete to completion... but I can't seem to select it to, uh, complete the autocomplete.

Nothing I do seems to work. Including putting it in quotes such as:

```
cd "..\bin\"
```

Note that Linux slashes are this way, "/", while the above cited slashes are Windows style "\".

How do I cd to the bin directory so I can erase that .dll file?

Comment: Do you know how those files ended up in /var/lib/* in the first place? If not, then it looks like someone has _already_ been at least partially succesful with an attack against you -- and if you don't know what else they've been able to drop into your file system, you should give some thought to whether you can trust the machine without backing up your data, wiping the disk, and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: You are right Henning. Pragmatically speaking for now, I am satisfied with my remediation efforts. I have run ClamAV, and applied all the latest yum security updates to the box. For me, this server is a personal dev box / tinker machine and ranks lower in priority than some of my other efforts. However, if it gives me any more trouble, yes I would reestablish the server from scratch. I appreciate the thoughtful comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe that is an actual directory, I suspect that that is just a file with backslashes. Try deleting that file directly and it should be removed.

This will work: `rm '..\lib\plugin\amd.dll'`

I am also not sure how smart `cd` is on a CentOS system, it might only show autocomplete options for directories only. In which you would have to do `rmdir '..\lib\plugin\amd.dll'` (assuming it is empty). You can determine this by running `ls -l` in the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/` directory and seeing if that is a file or a directory and then issue the correct command accordingly.

On a Linux system the backslahes are just treated as characters in the file name and not directory separators. Therefore there is no special distinction when using them in the context of directories. Backslashes are typically used as escape characters for special characters.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  It IS just a file with backslashes and dots in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems.  You don't say what you're typing before autocomplete, which complicates matters, and you're behaving as if that's a file in another directory, which it's not - backslashes aren't path separators in unix, as you've noted, they're just characters in a filename.

As for the second, stop trying to `cd`.  Shell won't autocomplete that filename to `cd`, whatever you do, because it's not a directory.  The file is in `.`, just `rm` it.

As to the first, you **can't** just type `..` to autocomplete, as that's not an unambiguous match (the directory also contains `..`, as it must).  You can't just type `..\` to autocomplete, because backslash is a metacharacter which escapes the one that follows it, and shell doesn't know what that is - it could be anything, or nothing.  If, however, you type

```
rm ..\\
```

then hit `TAB` (assuming this is bash), then the filename should get filled in correctly.  I just tried it, and it worked for me (bash 4.3.42(1) under Fedora 22).

Answer (score -1):

It's a Symlink (Symbolic Link).

If you run the command: ls -l amd.dll

you'd see something like:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Sep 22  2013 amd.dll -> ..\lib\plugin\amd.dll

Which means that the actual file is located here:

/var/lib/mysql/lib/plugin/amd.dll

Answer (score -2):

If it is really a directory, try to issue `cd '..\lib\plugin\amd.dll'`(please note the single quotes, rather than double quotes)

If it is a file, use `rm '..\lib\plugin\amd.dll'` (again, pay attention at the single quotes)

Comment: This is not going to work.  It's not a directory.

Comment: If it is not a directory, it can simply substitute `cd` with `rm`

Comment: That is true, but I think you'll find it's already been said.

Comment: True. I re-read your answer and you have a point ;)